# Show that the operator $S\in B(Y)$ (the set of bounded linear operators from $Y\to Y$)

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I am having trouble with the following problem:

*"Suppose we have an operator $S:Y\to Y$, where,*

$$S(g)(y)=g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

*and where we have $Y=C([0,1])$, equipped with the uniform norm defined as,*

$$\|g\|_u=\sup_{y\in[0,1]}|g(y)|$$

*Show that $S\in B(Y)$"*

Here is what I have attempted so far:

I understand that a bounded linear operator must satisfy the following:

$$ T\in B(X) \implies\|Tx\|\le k\|x\|,\,\forall x\in X$$

And that we should make use of the fact that,

$$|g(y)|\le \sup_{y\in [0,1]}|g(y)|=\|g\|_u$$

Since we know that our operator $S$ is mapping from functions $g\in C([0,1])$ onto other functions $f\in C([0,1])$ we can think of $Sg(y)$ as another function in our space. As such,

$$|Sg(y)|=|g(y)-\int_0^1g(x)dx|$$

$$=|g(y)+ (-\int_0^1g(x)dx)|$$

$$\le |g(y)|+|(-\int_0^1g(x)dx)|$$

$$=|g(y)|+|\int_0^1g(x)dx|$$

$$\le|g(y)|+\int_0^1|g(x)|dx$$

$$\le\|g\|_u+\int_0^1\|g\|_udx$$

However it has gotten to the point that I don't know if what I am doing is right, not how to get back on track to satisfying the property defined above that all bounded operators must meet, involving $k$.

Comment: So the final expression is bounded by $2\|g\|_{u}$.

Comment: Ahh, I was forgetting that $\|g\|_u$ is a real number, so we can take it out of the integral. Cheers!